# Pandas join grouped dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe that tells me how many trrips a certain ship has sailed on a given day:

```
   trip  ship       Date
0     1     1 2020-03-09
1     2     1 2020-03-09
2     3     1 2020-03-09
3     4     1 2020-03-09
4     5     2 2020-03-13
5     6     2 2020-03-13
6     7     2 2020-03-13
7     8     3 2020-03-22
8     9     3 2020-03-22

L= ['year', 'month','day']
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2020, 2020,2020,2020,2020,2020, 2020,2020,2020],
                   'month': [3, 3,3,3,3, 3, 3, 3,3 ],
                   'day': [9, 9,9,9,13,13,13,22,22],
                   'trip': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                   'ship':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[L],format='%Y%m%d')
df.drop(L,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

I then count  the number of trips within each group 'ship' as:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ship'])['trip'].count().reset_index() #counte the number  of trips within each group ship.
```

How do I assign from the old dataframe df1 the date within that group 'ship' to the new df2?

Desired result look like:

```
   ship  trip Date 
0     1     4 2020-03-09
1     2     3 2020-03-13
2     3     2 2020-03-22
```

Comment: instead of merging you can use `agg` : `df.groupby(['ship']).agg({'trip':'count','Date':'first'}).reset_index()` or with merge : `df2.merge(df.drop_duplicates('ship'),on='ship',suffixes=('','_y'))[df.columns]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `ship,date` in case the ships are travelling on different date and you want trips each day.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ship','Date']).agg({'trip':'count'})

ship    Date    trip
1   2020-03-09  4
2   2020-03-13  3
3   2020-03-22  2
```

If you want trips count from the first sale day

```
df.groupby(['ship']).agg(FirstDate = ('Date','first'),trips = ('trip','count'))

ship FirstDate  trips       
1   2020-03-09  4
2   2020-03-13  3
3   2020-03-22  2
```

Comment: What about when your date is given as y-m-d h:m:s and you want to have the date grouped by as y-m-d?

Comment: if the `y-m-d h:m:s` is in datetime format you can use `.date()` to remove time and get just y-m-d.

or if it is in string format  you can use 
`datetime.strptime('yourdate in ymdhms', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()`

Comment: Apply the any of above methods to the whole columns
`df['New_Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.date())`

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems that every ship has got only one `Date` value. In that case, you can add `Date` column to `.groupby()` method, like this:

```
>>> df2 = df.groupby(['ship', 'Date'])['trip'].count().reset_index()
>>> print(df2)
   ship       Date  trip
0     1 2020-03-09     4
1     2 2020-03-13     3
2     3 2020-03-22     2
```

Comment: What about when your date is given as y-m-d h:m:s and you want to have the date grouped by as y-m-d?

Comment: You can convert the date column to another format and call `.groupby()` afterwards.